# Keeping PageView Fragment's View from disposal

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter, android-pageradapter

I have an Android Application implementing a PageView with Tabs found here: https://github.com/sbpc/ajavacc The PageView loads its Fragments and displays everything properly; but occasionally the individual Fragments become disposed. Is there a way to either store the Fragment's state, prevent the pages from being disposed; or do I need to save the values which construct each page to a file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `MainPagerAdapter` is already using `FragmentPagerAdapter` which keeps the created `Fragment`s in memory. You can go one step further and add the method `setRetainInstance(true)` to each `Fragment` in the `ViewPager`. This should work. You can read more about this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29).